# How to seperate a column element in a view using a delimiter?

Tags: sql, asp.net

In the view I would like to display the column winners1 and winners2 with a newline after each comma.

`winners1` column equals = `"john doe,mary john,elvis thins"`

`winners2` column equals = `"john doe,mary john,elvis thins"`

output:

```
john doe
mary john
elvis thins
```

Code:

```
ViewBag.getAwardWinners = db.Database.SqlQuery<summary_winners>(
    @"SELECT * FROM table1  WHERE YEAR ([month_year_winners]) ={0} ",
    year
).ToList();
```

View:

```
foreach (var item in ViewBag.getAwardWinners) {
    <tr>
        <td>@item.winners1</td> 
        <td>@item.winners2</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: just replace, with \n (newline).

Comment: Newline or a new row?

Comment: probably the best term is line break

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SQL function `REPLACE()` to substitute a newline for each occurence of a comma in the original column. You did not tag the RDBMS that you are using, but this function is supported by most of them (at least SQLServer, Oracle and MySQL).

This will require you to explicitly list the columns that you want to `SELECT` (which is basically a good pratice anyway).

Consider:

```
SELECT 
    REPLACE(winners1, ',', '\n') winners1, 
    REPLACE(winners2, ',', '\n') winners2,
    -- other columns to SELECT... 
FROM table1 t1 
WHERE YEAR ([month_year_winners]) = {0}
```